# How to configure many-to-many relationship using code first fluent mapping that is uni-directional

Tags: entity-framework, many-to-many, code-first

I have a User class and Role class that need a many-to-many relationship.  Provided that User has a collection or Roles, and vice-versa, I can figure out how to specify the mapping in the fluent API e.g. (in the Role mapping):

```
    this.HasMany(t => t.Users)
        .WithMany(t => t.Roles)
        .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("UsersToRoles");
                m.MapLeftKey("RoleId");
                m.MapRightKey("UserId");
            });
```

However, whereas I do want the User (class) to have a collection of Roles, I *don't* want the Role (class) to have a collection of users as, typically, there might be very many Users in each role  -  and I don't want the risk that accessing a Role instance might cause all those Users to be loaded.  So two questions:

1. Am I right to be concerned? (I have memories problems back in the early days of .edmx where spurious bi-directional relationships caused huge performance issues until removed)?
2. If so, how can I specify the many-to-many relationship if there isn't a collection on both classes?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Am I right to be concerned? (I have memories problems back in the early days of .edmx where spurious bi-directional relationships caused
>   huge performance issues until removed)?

The risk might be there if you allow lazy loading. You could remove the `virtual` modifier from the `Role.Users` collection to be sure that this collection can never be loaded lazily, only on explicit request using `Include(r => r.Users)` for example. The "spurious bi-directional relationships" you mean with EF 4.0 were probably with POCOs that contained autogenerated relationship fixup code which indeed sometimes caused unwished side effects (but also mainly due to lazy loading).

> If so, how can I specify the many-to-many relationship if there isn't a collection on both classes?

You must configure the many-to-many relationship from the `User` side and then use `WithMany()` without lambda parameter:

```
this.HasMany(t => t.Roles)
    .WithMany()
    .Map(m =>
        {
            m.ToTable("UsersToRoles");
            m.MapLeftKey("UserId");
            m.MapRightKey("RoleId");
        });
```

`this` is an `EntityTypeConfiguration<User>` in this case. Also note the reversal of "Left" and "Right" in the mapping.